# checking number input in range c

Tags: c

I am new to C code . Today I try to make a check input loop with error line 
I want it to print error line whenever input is smaller than `5` 
But it's wrong and I can't fix it .

```
int x=0,n, s1=0 , s2=1 ;
float s3=0;
do{
    printf("\ninput n: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n must be bigger than 5");
}while(n<=5);
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    s1=s1+i;
    s2=s2*i;
    s3= s3+ (float)(1/i);
}
printf("s1 = %d\ns2 = %d\ns3= %.4f ", s1, s2 ,s3);
```

Comment: how is it wrong? we can't help if you don't describe the problem

Comment: What goes wrong? WHat happens if you print what you end up with in `n` to help you debug?

Comment: `s3= s3+ (float)(1/i);`-- you probably want `s3 = s3 + 1.0 / i;` or `s3 = s3 + 1 / ((float) i);`

Comment: yeah when i enter 4 it print n must be bigger than 5 but when i enter 6 it still print n must be bigger than 5 and process to for loop
i just want it to stop print error line when i input number bigger than 5

Comment: Have a look at @lone_worrior's answer.

Comment: Just think about it.  After the value is read by `scanf`, what is the very next thing it does?  That's right, it prints your message about `n` having to be bigger than 5.  It hasn't checked the value yet.  It always prints the message.  So, add a check:  Don't print the message unless `n` is less than or equal to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by error line you mean this line `printf("n must be bigger than 5");` and you want to print this line only when n is smaller than 5 then just put `if` condition there
like this:

```
  if(n<=5){
    printf("n must be bigger than 5");
}
```